# php setlocale - no locale for azeri language

Tags: php, sorting, locale

i would like to sort an array of strings in Azerbaijan language alphabetical order. but there is no locale for Azeri Latin code page.

how can i sort the array properly?

thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try building keys from the original string replacing azeri alphabet characters to a sequence of characters within ASCII table (lets say, `"A" => chr(128), "B" => char(129), "C" => chr(130), "Ç" => chr(131) , ...` ), making a hash ( *key* => _original_value_ ) and then using [`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort)